# Know geographical origin of Facebook post reactions

Tags: facebook, api, social-networking

I administrate a Facebook page, and, for a particular post, i'd need to know where post reactions came from.

For example, "you got N sigh reactions from Italy and M from Germany, while you got X grr reactions from Italy and Y from France".

I didn't find how to do it checking Facebook insights and taking a look at Facebook APIs reference, any idea if it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> for a particular post, i'd need to know where post reactions came from.
>
> For example, "you got N sigh reactions from Italy and M from Germany, while you got X grr reactions from Italy and Y from France".

That data is not available.

All available metrics are listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/insights, and the few that return data by country are only on the page level, not on a post level. (Apart from video posts, that have a few viewing related metrics broken down to country level.)

Individual reaction types are not available by country on any level.